# Can you cast Planar Binding on a creature that you cannot hear or see?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, targeting

Most spells state that you "do x to a creature you can see" or "do x at a point you can see within range", but [*planar binding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-binding) does not have any such statement.

Does this mean that you can cast it on a creature that stays within range for the duration, but is not visible to you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, as long as you have a clear path to it

As you mentioned, *planar binding* does not require you to see your target. So you absolutely could cast this spell on an invisible target that was within range for the entire 1-hour casting time.

Note, however, that the [standard rules for spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#AClearPathtotheTarget) would still apply:

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can’t be behind total cover. (PHB, p. 204)

If the reason you can't see your target is that there is some solid obstruction between you and it, then it is not a valid target.

So you could only target a creature with this spell (at the end of its casting) if you had a clear path to it. If you can't see it because it's invisible or you're blind, but there's no obstruction between you and it, this spell will still work. But if you can't see it because it's behind something, the creature will not be able to be targeted, and the spell will fail.

Comment: You mention "at the end of its casting", does that mean the caster could shelter behind a wall for the entirety of the casting except for the last 6 seconds?

Comment: Probably not. The rules on areas of effect indicate that if a creature is behind total cover from a point of origin, they aren't within that spell's area of effect. I didn't include that because they technically don't define an area of effect here, but a range. But a reasonable extrapolation of those rules would say that if a creature was behind a wall for part of the casting, it wasn't within range the whole time (because it was outside of the spell's area of effect).